# SQL Server : constraints and foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have an assignment where I must

1. Create an Entity Relationship diagram of a particular situation, and
2. Write up the SQL code to represent the diagram

I am new to SQL Server, but I have a table `class` that has a primary key `CRN varchar(10)(UNN)` and two foreign keys, `emp_id varchar(20) (NN)` which has a 1 mandatory relationship with instructor, and `room_number varchar(5) (UNN)` which also has a 1 mandatory relationship with `Classroom`.

My code for table `Class`:

```
CREATE TABLE class
(
     CRN varchar(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
     emp_id varchar(20), 
     room_number varchar(5), 
     enrollment smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT pk_class PRIMARY KEY (CRN),
     CONSTRAINT fk_class 
         FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES instructor (emp_id),
     CONSTRAINT fk_class 
         FOREIGN KEY (room_number) REFERENCES classroom (room_number)
);
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Constraint "FK_CLASS" already exists; SQL statement:
>   CREATE TABLE class
>   (CRN varchar(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   emp_id varchar(20),
>   room_number varchar(5),
>   enrollment smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>   CONSTRAINT pk_class PRIMARY KEY (CRN),
>   CONSTRAINT fk_class FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES instructor (emp_id),
>   CONSTRAINT fk_class FOREIGN KEY (room_number) REFERENCES classroom (room_number) ) [90045-193]

I have seen many different examples on how to make a table have two foreign keys, but have had no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each constraint MUST have a unique name, just like every table must have a unique name. Maybe something like fk_class_emp_id and fk_class_room_number instead?

Comment: You need a unique name for each primary key and foreign key constraint. You've named both your foreign key constraints the same thing. Thus the error. Your names in general are way, way too vague and generic. But specifically, your FK names should indicate what the FK relationship is... FK_class_instructor, and FK_class_classroom are possible suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contraints must have a unique name, and you are using name `fk_class` twice. So naming the one `fk_instructor` and the other `fk_classroom` should solve the problem.

Note that there is a shorter notation, which avoids such issues:

```
CREATE TABLE class (
  CRN varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
  emp_id varchar(20) references instructor (emp_id), 
  room_number varchar(5) REFERENCES classroom (room_number), 
  enrollment smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```